# How to align selectlist in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a vf page where I need to align two picklist with the above textbox.

Below is my pic and vf page -

```
        <apex:form >
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!clearErrors}" name="clearErrors" rerender="foo" />
            <apex:outputPanel id="foo" />
        </apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="RFP Edit" subtitle="{!IF(rfp.Id != null, rfp.Name, 'New RFP')}" />
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false">    
                <!--JL - 3-19-15 - Field now required -->        
                <!-- <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="requiredForSubmit"> -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <!--JL - 3-19-15 - Field now required -->
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.RFP__c.Fields.Primary_Target_Audience__c.Label}" />
                    <apex:outputPanel id="primaryTargetAudience" layout="block" styleClass="requiredForSubmitInput">
                        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                        <!--JL - 3-19-15 - Field now required -->
                        <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!rfp.Primary_Target_Audience__c}" styleClass="fullWidth"/> -->
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rfp.Primary_Target_Audience__c}" styleClass="fullWidth" required="true"/>
                        <!--JL - 3-19-15 - Field now required -->
<!--                         <apex:inputField value="{!rfp.Primary_Target_Audience__c}" styleClass="fullWidth" required="true" /> -->
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <!--JL - 3-19-15 - Field now required -->
               <!-- <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="requiredForSubmit"> -->
  <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->           
    <apex:actionregion >


    <div style="width:84.9%; float:right;">
    <label style="Vertical-align:top;float:left;">Country:</label>
    <apex:selectList value="{!discountScheduleID}" size="1" styleClass=" chzn-select" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" />
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!dept}"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
    </div>


    <div style="width:82%; float:right;">
    <label style="float:left;margin:20px;">Geography:</label>

   <apex:outputPanel id="geographies" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput">

    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedGeographyIds }" multiselect="true" id="selectedGeographies" styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" >

            <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllName}" id="movieTextBox"></apex:selectOptions>

        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
    </apex:actionregion> 

    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->   
       </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your `apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"` you need to change this into `columns="2"` or you can create table for same

```
 <apex:actionregion >
<table> <tr><td>
        <apex:selectList value="{!discountScheduleID}" size="1" styleClass=" chzn-select" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" />
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!dept}"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
</td><td>
       <apex:outputPanel id="geographies" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput">
       <apex:selectList value="{!selectedGeographyIds }" multiselect="true" id="selectedGeographies" styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllName}" id="movieTextBox"></apex:selectOptions>

            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

or you can use div and some css

```
<apex:actionregion >
<div style="width:50%; float:left;">
        <apex:selectList value="{!discountScheduleID}" size="1" styleClass=" chzn-select" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" />
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!dept}"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
</div><div style="width:50%; float:right;">
       <apex:outputPanel id="geographies" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput">
       <apex:selectList value="{!selectedGeographyIds }" multiselect="true" id="selectedGeographies" styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllName}" id="movieTextBox"></apex:selectOptions>

            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
            </apex:actionregion>
```

Comment: Tushar.. I tried some css. But i need the labels should be in align with above text. "Primary Target Audience". Can u plzz check

Comment: You need to apply margin-right for this. this all happen because of action:region so if you don't need this you can remove this.

Comment: I need action:region..very impt...Any workaround???

Comment: margin-right will work or you have to apply other css

Comment: margin-right on which i will apply??